# Display Text Over Hover in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add text on hover over an image inside a row and col-md-3. I want it to change opacity to set ideal while displaying text in centered inside the image.

I have the opacity hover down but I'm struggling with the data-hover class and I have no clue where to place the text I want inside HTML and CSS

I've included a fiddle here with all the work I have accomplished thus far: https://jsfiddle.net/a8u05mw1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://www.roys.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/FASHION/MENSWEAR-AW16-JOULES-COAT.jpg>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b1/5e/38/b15e38cd4864c85a52897d906a88710c.jpg>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56b6a4bd07eaa0d2d0eddb7f/58678682bebafb6e8b0a4e2a/5867868b893fc0dff9edd97d/1483179664063/Andrew+Belliot-011.jpg?format=500w>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper img {
width: 100%;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.col-md-3 {
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper img:hover {
opacity: 0.8;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: Mr. Gabriel Pozo can you expect https://jsfiddle.net/bjayanta/nsg50gfw/9/

Comment: @JayantaBiswas Thank-you sir! Works flawlessly! :)

Comment: your welcome sir. is it work for you?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you!

Comment: mention not. your welcome again sir.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer 1: Without Bootstrap

[jsfiddle answer 1](https://jsfiddle.net/Darkvoldorious/ehgmr7c8/1/)

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
    
          <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg style="width:100%;">
          <div class="img-hover-text centered">Your text here</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b1/5e/38/b15e38cd4864c85a52897d906a88710c.jpg>
          <div class="img-hover-text centered">Your text here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img class="img-responsive" src=https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56b6a4bd07eaa0d2d0eddb7f/58678682bebafb6e8b0a4e2a/5867868b893fc0dff9edd97d/1483179664063/Andrew+Belliot-011.jpg?format=500w>
          <div class="img-hover-text centered">Your text here</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I removed the image which is no more available.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* original example from question */
.img-responsive:hover + .img-hover-text {
  display: block;
}

.img-hover-text:hover { 
  /* needed for the text to stay visible
  when the cursor it just over it.
  */
  display: block;
}

.img-hover-text {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

### Answer 2: With Bootstrap

[jsfiddle answer 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Darkvoldorious/8znqth79/44/)

I made a new example inspired with your code, but using [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) from Booststrap / Popper.js. I used the [bootstrap starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) to quickstart the use of Boostrap.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg style="width:100%;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="This is a Tooltip">
      <div class="img-hover-text centered">Your text here</div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
      Tooltip on top
    </button>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.img-responsive:hover + .img-hover-text {
  display: block;
}

.img-hover-text:hover { 
  /* needed for the text to stay visible
  when the cursor it just over it.
  */
  display: block;
}

.img-hover-text {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```js
// Enable tooltip everywhere
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

[image: Example with tooltips]

### Explaining Answer 1:

You want two things:

1. First, center some text over an image.
2. Then, apply a hover effect on the text so that it only appears when the cursor is hovering the image.

You can get a cool tutorial on how to center text over an image [here | w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp).

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will give you the following picture:

[image: centered text over image]

Warning: Don't be like me. Don't waste your time on a `<p>`. Use a `<div>` for the text directly.

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <p class="centered">Not Centered</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise you will see this:

[image: Not centered text over image]

Ok, now we have our centered text. Time to make it disappear. Let's go back to your code and modify it.

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/61/fe/e661fe4b71debff151e6eb3fcd670bbe.jpg style="width:100%;">
  <div class="img-hover-text centered">Your text here</div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-responsive:hover + .img-hover-text {
  display: block;
}

.img-hover-text {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

However, if we stop there, something will be wrong. When we hover the cursor right on top of the text area, the text disappear! To correct that, add a last css rule:

```css
/* needed for the text to stay visible
  when the cursor it just over it. */
.img-hover-text:hover { 
  display: block;
}
```

### Explaining answer 2

The idea is not to do the stuff we made by hand, by using a library: namely Popper.js which fortunately is used by Boostrap. We include the tooltip with `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="This is a Tooltip"` inside the element we want to display the tooltip on hover. Here inside `<img>`.

To make is works, we also need to import the necessary library. Don't forget the `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` at the end, just before closing `</body>` flag.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short for those looking for a Boostrap answer.

Add a [*tooltip*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) in the flag you want.

```html
<img src=... data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="This is a Tooltip">
```

```js
// Enable tooltip everywhere
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Don't forget to add Popper.js which is needed for the tooltip.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```